# Log4Net config with .NET Core app

Tags: .net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration

I need to use log4net on a new .NET Core app that references some just written assemblies which uses log4net.
I've searched around but all the examples passes just a `FileInfo` to the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure`  but using the latest version asks for a first paremeter of type `ILoggerRepository repository`

What should I pass?

My code is

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var configuration = builder.Build();

        ContainerConfig.RegisterDependencies(configuration);
        MappingConfig.RegisterMapping();


        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"\config.log4net");

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(null, fileInfo);



        var core = ContainerWrapper.Container.GetInstance<ICore>();

        core.StartAsync().Wait();

        Console.Write("Press a key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But with `null` it crashes

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the default `repository` via the statement here below,
and pass that one as argument of the `Configure` method.

```
ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

Depending on your setup, you might need to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead.